# Slow correlated query

Tags: sql, mariadb

Hello I am running the query below, but its proving very slow to load it there any wat to speed up the query possibly not using correlated queries, I was thinking that using a left join to fix it but im starting to get a bit tunnel vision on this, thanks for any help.

```
SELECT
        e._User_Id,
        e.Ref_Claim_Id,
        e.First_Name,
        e.Surname,
        e.City,
        e.Rta_Claim_Id,
        e.Date_Created,
        e.Status,
        IF(
          _CMC_User_Id > 0,
          (
            SELECT
              Email_Id
            FROM
              user_account
            WHERE
              User_Id = e._User_Id
          ),
          (
            SELECT
              IF(
                Company_Name IS NULL, ' In-house',
                Company_Name
              )
            FROM
              employee_details
            WHERE
              _User_Id = e._User_Id
          )
        ) AS Company_Name,
        (
             SELECT
               Solicitor_Ref_Id
             FROM
               claim_assign_solicitor
             WHERE
               e.Ref_Claim_Id = _Ref_Claim_Id AND _Accident_Type_Id = 1
             ) AS Solicitor_Ref,

         (
             SELECT
             _Solicitor_User_Id
             FROM
             claim_assign_solicitor
             WHERE
               e.Ref_Claim_Id = _Ref_Claim_Id AND _Accident_Type_Id = 1
           ) AS Solicitor_User_Id,
        (
             SELECT
             Company_Name
           FROM
             employee_details
           WHERE
             Solicitor_User_Id = _User_Id
         ) AS Solicitor_Name
      FROM
        rta_claim as e;
```

Comment: Which database are you using? What does the data in your tables represent? What does the query do? Have you set any indexes?

Comment: MariaDB is the database, the data in the table represents some customers plus the id, name and reference number of a solicitor attached to said case. the query is responsible for pull in the user data along with the data of the solicitor handling the case.

Comment: Thank you for answering my comment. However, this information should be part of your question. Other useful information would be the schema of the tables involved, the indexes you have set, and, if possible, an `EXPLAIN` output. You could also remove the little PHP code that is left, this is clearly a database question. Also have a look at: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) The better the information in your question, the higher the change you will get an useful answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will include all of that information next time I rarely ask for help here as I like to try and work things out, but this is giving me a bit of a headache.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Haha, yes, I can see why. If I have to hazard a guess as to why your query is slow it is probably due to the many sub-queries that are executed many-many times. You could try to restructure it into a multiple table `JOIN` query.

Comment: For a "minimal reproducible example" you could use: http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I didn't make any mistake , here is how to rewrite your query:

```
SELECT
    e._User_Id,
    e.Ref_Claim_Id,
    e.First_Name,
    e.Surname,
    e.City,
    e.Rta_Claim_Id,
    e.Date_Created,
    e.Status,
    IF(_CMC_User_Id > 0, Email_Id,COALESCE(Company_Name,' In-house') AS Company_Name,
    cas.Solicitor_Ref_Id AS Solicitor_Ref,
    cas._Solicitor_User_Id AS Solicitor_User_Id,
    ed2.Company_Name AS Solicitor_Name
FROM
    rta_claim as e
    join user_account ua on ua.User_Id = e._User_Id
    join employee_details ed on ed._User_Id = e._User_Id
    join claim_assign_solicitor cas on e.Ref_Claim_Id = cas._Ref_Claim_Id
        AND cas._Accident_Type_Id = 1
    join employee_details ed2 on cas.Solicitor_User_Id = ed2._User_Id
```